# State channel implementation

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ethereumjs

Say I have a data chain, a party is moving data to a party and so on and so on, and I'd like to trace exactly what party touched what data (given my data has an ID).

I wouldn't like to store this on-chain therefore I would like to come up with a state channel solution for that.

My assumption would be the most optimal way would be to save some sort of channel state on-chain, make lots of transactions on the state-channel, maintaing an API between all parties and once every X minutes write the channel state on-chain, using a Merkle Tree.

Now this is very abstract, I don't understand this to detail and I'd like to know how am I to implement such "checkpoint" on-chain and some guidelines on what's the best approach.

Comment: Did you manage to arrive at a solution? What you describe sounds very similar to something I'm putting together. The checkpoint I intend to use is simply anchoring a hash and timestamp to the blockchain and the DAPP generates a JSON-LD chainpoint-proof as a form of proof of existence. However, the ability to maintain state for an unknown amount of time is a requirement as well, which I imagine could be simply maintained using Solidity's equivalent of class properties.